# aFileChooser error, get file path shows error in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-afilechooser

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CHOOSER:   
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            final Uri uri = data.getData();

            // Get the File path from the Uri
            String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);

            // Alternatively, use FileUtils.getFile(Context, Uri)
            if (path != null && FileUtils.isLocal(path)) {
                File file = new File(path);
            }
        }
        break;
     }
   }
```

I'm copying this code from github,this link https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser,I'm putting this code inside a fragment. In this line, it shows error

```
 String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);
```

Showing this error:

```
The method getPath(Context, Uri) in the type FileUtils is not applicable for the arguments (PagesFragment, Uri)
```

Anyone can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this,

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CHOOSER:   
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                final Uri uri = data.getData();

                // Get the File path from the Uri
                String path = FileUtils.getPath(getActivity(), uri);

                // Alternatively, use FileUtils.getFile(Context, Uri)
                if (path != null && FileUtils.isLocal(path)) {
                    File file = new File(path);
                }
            }
            break;
         }
       }
```

Comment: Thanks! it works.. too tired of coding.. facing this problem again.

Comment: 2 more minutes, be patient my friend, coz I upvoted it, it needs 10 minutes to enable me to accept.